# Swift Navigation Bar animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, navigationbar

I try to make my iOS application more attractive using animations and I recently downloaded the official Unsplash app. So does anybody have an experience with Navigation Bar animations [like this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aQTXHhFvfnPfscUghpKmOCqCsJY42gVQ/view?usp=sharing)? Are there any ideas how to make that transition?

I tried this for the `collection view` and its background:

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let delta =  scrollView.contentOffset.y - oldContentOffset.y

    if delta > 0 && backgroundTopAnchor!.constant >= CGFloat(68.0) && scrollView.contentOffset.y >= -15 {
        backgroundTopAnchor?.constant -= delta
        scrollView.contentOffset.y -= delta

    }

    if delta < 0 && backgroundTopAnchor!.constant <= CGFloat(211.0) && scrollView.contentOffset.y <= -15 {
        backgroundTopAnchor?.constant -= delta
        scrollView.contentOffset.y -= delta
    }

    oldContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset

    adjuctAlpha()

}
```

And it worked, but a bit laggy, without bounce effect and overlapping on fast scrolling.

I believe that there is a simple way to do it without fast constraints changing, using a `scroll view` or something. So I hope you can help me, guys :)

Comment: I think there is a view on top of viewcontroller that contains searchbar and its alpha set to 0, when scroll view scrolls up, the header goes away and at the same time mentioned view's alpha become 1

Comment: I thought a lot about that and made the best that I can for my app, so thanks :)